# @QueryParam to restrict only one value in URL

Tags: java, rest

My URL is http://example.com/api/orders?stateCode=10 and when I try to access the URl its working perfectly. In my condition http://example.com/api/orders?stateCode=TX&id=10 this should not work. Basically the URL should have only one queryparam value not more than that. Is to posiible to restrict the URL to accept only one queryparm in JAVA Rest API

Comment: Please provide more info. What framework do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to restrict a URL when it has the correct information?  Quoting [Postel's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) "Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others". As long as the caller passed in stateCode, the URL should be treated valid.